# Fast Reports Preview - C # MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fastreport

Good afternoon. I have reports with parameters, before forming reports, I would like to make a preview. How to use "webReport.Report.ShowPrepared ()"?

```
item = reportDB.SelectFirst(Convert.ToInt64(showID));
reportDB.SelectBinaryFile(ref item);
var r = new FastReport.Report();
r.LoadFromString(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(item.ReportBody));
WebReport webReport = new WebReport(); 
webReport.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);  
webReport.Height = Unit.Percentage(100); 
if (1==1)//проверка на рус язык
    webReport.LocalizationFile = "~\\Translation\\Russian.frl";

SetUserInfo(ref r);

webReport.AutoWidth = true;
webReport.AutoHeight = true;

webReport.Report =r;

webReport.PrevPage();
ViewBag.WebReport = webReport.GetHtml();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the official documentation if Fast reports you can use like below.
First you needs to check whether the report is prepared, if prepared returns true boolean value simply you can call the showprepared() method.

```
webReport.Load("report1.frl");
webReport.Prepare(true);
webReport.ShowPrepared();
```

if you wants to use some modal window and needs to return to the privious pages then you can use it like below.

```
void ShowPrepared(bool modal,Form owner)
```

The same as the previous method. The ow ner parameter determines a
window that owns the preview window.

Please read more from here to implement it in better way.
[Official Documentation Fast Reports](https://www.fast-report.com/public_download/FRNetProgrammerManual-en.pdf)

Comment: @zig8953 Glad it helped to fix your problem.